# Woocommerce variations per category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a way to add product variations per category. For example: Category t-shirts: -> variants: size, color, etc.

I know it can be added per product, but that can a huge thing when there are lots of products. It would be easier to simply set them on category, since this is what my client would like.

Hope I explained it clearly.

Thanks.

Comment: Woocommerce does not provide us this feature.

Comment: I know, but is there a plugin or so that has that feature?

Comment: Nobody has an idea?